# Angular Component/Controller resolve $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, controller, components, resolve

I am trying to adapt to Angular's component (from code generated by Angular Fullstack Generator). 
I tried to configure the routes to resolve "query" as per below:

```
angular.module('paizaApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<main query="$resolve.query"></main>',
      resolve:{
        query:function(){return null;}
      },


 .state('starred',{
    url:'/users/:userId/starred',
    template: '<main query="$resolve.query"></main>',
    resolve:{
        query:function($stateParams){
          return {stars:$stateParams.userId};
        }
      }
  })
  .state('users',{
    url:'/users/:userId',
    template: '<main query="$resolve.query"></main>',
    resolve:{
      query:function($stateParams){
        return {user:$stateParams.userId}
      }
    }
```

The following are the codes for the controller/component.

```
class MainController {

    constructor($http, $scope, socket, Auth, query) {
      this.$http = $http;
      this.socket = socket;
      this.awesomeThings = [];

      $scope.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn;
      $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

   $onInit() {
      this.$http.get('/api/things',{params:{query:query}})
        .then(response => {
          this.awesomeThings = response.data;
          this.socket.syncUpdates('thing', this.awesomeThings);
        });
    }////////
////////////////////////////////////// etc..


  angular.module('paizaApp')
    .component('main', {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
      bindings:{query:'='},
      controller: MainController

    });
```

I am getting an error message - unknown query provider. However if I remove query from the constructor then the error message is "query is not defined".
Can you please see where I have gone wrong and whether I am supposed to inject the "query" variable into the controller? I am new to Angular 1, not to mention Angular 2.

Update: I have also tried something like this but didn't work:

```
angular.module('paizaApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<main></main>',
      resolve:{
        query:function(){return null;}
      },
      controller:function($scope,query){
        $scope.query=query
      }
```

And:

```
angular.module('paizaApp')
    .component('main', {
      templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',

      controller: MainController,
      scope:{query:'='}

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't inject `query` on controller `constructor`. You could have do that if you have specified `MyController` as controller for state.

The `query` resolve is already passed in component `bindings`. You can directly get the value of `query` resolve inside `this.query`

Comment: I changed all references to query to this.query inside the controller function and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: spoke too soon. error messages are gone but this.query returns undefined. I still need to find out how the value of resolved query gets into the controller function

Comment: @AAllen as I can see the value should be `null`, correct?

Comment: it should return null not undefined. I have other routes as well which I am adding to my code above that are supposed to return values...